# Why wasn't the Bank of Evil called Lehman Brothers?

Tags: minions

In **Despicable Me** (2010), the Bank of Evil has a sub-title: "Formerly Lehman Brothers".

[image]

A subtle and clever joke, this reference seems to be missing from the Minions universe in **Minions: The Rise of Gru** (2022), which chronologically pre-dates Despicable Me in story and features Gru as a child, the bank is not called Lehman Brothers, but simply the Bank of Evil.

Are we (those of the audience who remember) supposed to ignore the inconsistency? Did Illumination decide it would cause confusion and drop it? Or did they just think the joke would no longer be funny, now that [the subprime mortgage crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subprime_mortgage_crisis) is no longer a current event with relevance for everyone? (Personally, I think it would have been even funnier to keep running with it, pretending Lehman is *of course* the infamous bank run by villains) Or maybe there were legal issues with using the name so directly this time around, even in parody? I'm just curious...

Comment: Pure guess: it's just passé, past its 'amuse by' date. Even the parents of small children going to see this in the cinema may actually be too young to remember it from 12 years ago. It would be like calling it 'Barings Bank'… too long ago to be immediately funny.

Comment: Yeah, I have no definitive answer, but jokes age.  Lehman Brothers failed in 2008.  Associating them directly with the Bank of Evil was funny in 2010.  To just have Lehman Brothers in a 2022 movie without even referencing the Bank of Evil would just confuse most people.

Comment: Barings Bank didn't cause a global financial crisis, an earthquake did. "In 1976, an 11-year-old Gru dreams to become a supervillain" - It'd have to still be named Lehman Brothers in 1976, which isn't funny. *Bank of Evil* is on its own. I was alive in 1995 and I've never heard of Barings, and I had to google what Lehman did. If it said a subsidiary of Enron, I wouldn't have had to google that. But that was 20y ago.

Comment: @Mazura - so basically you're agreeing with us - you're too young to get the references, hence it's passé.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm *old enough* to get the references and I didn't. There was "Enron" and then there was (the Global Financial Crisis of ) "2008". [The Big Short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Short_(film)) Wiki only says *Lehman* once. And it's only mentioned in the movie once towards the end. As far as I can tell the company does still exist. I'm just hoping the answer is *lawyers* otherwise this isn't very interesting.

Comment: @iandotkelly Yeah, your comment is probably the best "answer". I guess sometimes it's best to just let a joke live outside of the literal canon, and not look too deeply into it.